# 2 Pointers to same value and changing just one of them - Double linked list C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have a `class Node` with these attributes:

```
int value;
Node* next;
Node* prev;
```

I have a `class List` with an attribute `Node* first` when I initialize the list to know which one is the first node.

Assuming I have initialized 2 lists of `class List` with these values:

```
list1: 1 | 2 | 3 | NULL
list2: 6 | 7 | 8 | NULL
```

I want to get to a result where the lists are 'braided':

```
list1: 1 | 7 | 3 | NULL
list2: 6 | 2 | 8 | NULL
```

I'll use this method to `list1`:

```
void List::test(List list2){
Node* aux1 = first;   //first is 1
Node* aux3 = first;   //first is 1
Node* aux2 = list2.first;   //first of list2 is 6
Node* aux4 = list2.first;  //first of list2 is 6

aux1->next = aux2->next; //aux1->next is now 7 PERFECT
aux1->next->prev = aux1; //aux1->next->prev is now 1 PERFECT

//NOW I WANT TO CHECK aux3->next
cout << aux3->next <<endl; 
//IT PRINTS 7, LIKE AUX1->NEXT, BUT I WANT IT TO BE 2, LIKE IF IT'S BEEN DONE TO THE ORIGINAL LIST1!!
}
```

How can I make aux3 to stay in there? I thought if I point 2 pointers to just one Node, I could move one of those pointers without touching the attributes of the other pointer.

I know it's a silly problem, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: The node with `value==1` only has one `next` pointer. Either that pointer points to `2` node, or it points to `7` node. It can't point to both at the same time, magically deciding which node to go to depending on how the `1` node is reached. In other words: since `aux1 == aux3`, then necessarily `aux1->next == aux3->next`.

Comment: Try to cleanly separate the concepts of pointer and pointee. THan draw some pictures.

Comment: I got your ideas, thanks. I have drawings, and 'teorically' my code works. But the only thing I need is to 'attach' number 6 (of list2) with number 2 (of list1), so I need to have an auxiliar in number 2 to do that, but it doesn't work. How can I make it?

Comment: You should probably think in terms of some primitive operations like 'delete item from list' and 'insert item in list before/after'. You could then, with care, extract a node from list one, extract a node from list two, then insert the node from list one into list two, and insert the node from list two into list one. You face some issues with keeping positions cleanly, and iterating down longer lists without invalidating the iterators you're using. Doing this would allow you to write the 'braiding' function as a regular function instead of a member function, helping preserve symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial

```
aux1 -->|---|<--|---|
aux3 -->| 1 |-->| 2 |
        |___|   |___|

aux2 -->|---|<--|---|
aux4 -->| 6 |-->| 7 |
        |___|   |___|
```

after `aux1->next = aux2->next`

```
aux1 -->|---|<--- |---|
aux3 -->| 1 |\    | 2 | (no longer anything pointing at 2)
        |___| \   |___|
               \
aux2 -->|---|   \> |---|
aux4 -->| 6 | ---> | 7 |
        |___| <--- |___|
```

after `aux1->next->prev = aux1;`

```
aux1 -->|---|<---  |---|
aux3 -->| 1 |--->  | 7 |
        |___|   /> |___|
               /
aux2 -->|---| /
aux4 -->| 6 |/
        |___|
```

printing `aux3->next`

7

EDIT:

OK I think I understand what you are attempting now, you'll want to cache the second node in the first list while you manipulate it:

```
Node* aux1 = list1.first;   //first of list1 is 1
Node* aux2 = list2.first;   //first of list2 is 6
Node* aux3 = first->next;   //aux3 is 2

aux1->next = aux2->next; //aux1->next is now 7 PERFECT
aux1->next->prev = aux1; //aux1->next->prev is now 1 PERFECT
```

Now you need to use the cached 2 stored in aux 3 to regain your second list

```
aux2->next = aux3;
aux3->prev = aux2;
```

so you should now see:

```
aux1 -->|---|<--|---|
        | 1 |-->| 7 |
        |___|   |___|

aux2 -->|---|<--|---|
        | 6 |-->| 2 |
        |___|   |___|
```

Comment: Thanks for the drawings. My problem is this: I need to, after that part of the code, to link '6' of list2, to '2' in list1. So that's why I've been trying to use aux3. If I got aux3 in '2', I know can use 'aux2->next = aux3->next' (because aux1 is no longer pointing to 2).

Comment: Sorry that is a bit unclear, maybe take a step back and list what your actual goal is here?  I'm assuming this is an assignment of some kind?  If you want 2 copies of the same list, you'll need to make a clone, pointing to the same list with 2 pointers means they will both receive the same mutations.

Comment: Well it is. My goal is to do like a 'braid' of lists. If I have in list1: `1 - 2 - 3` and list2: `7 - 8 - 9`, I should get in list1: `1 - 7 - 3` and in list2: `7 - 2 - 9`.

Comment: Your problem if you have a single node with 7 in it, it cannot have both 3 and 2 in it's `next` value.

Comment: @GallaBlack: do you want the result to be `1 - 8 - 3` or `1 - 7 - 3` (as well as `7 - 2 - 9`)?  You've lost 8 in your comment (with no obvious reason why it was lost).

Comment: @HansAraya see my edit, I think that is what you are looking for?

Comment: SMOOTH! The edit worked perfectly! I knew it was silly, but I can't believe how I couldn't figure to put the aux3 after aux1 out!
Thanks to Kevin and everyone!